# Windows Console redirecting

Tags: java, windows-console

I'm trying to write a program, which starts an process for the windows console (cmd) and redirects the Input,Output and Errorstreams to System.in/out/err. Also, if the process is closed (via the command exit) my program should shutdown.

I've written a solution, that works kind of. The only problem is my used thread don't notice the process is shutted down. Also I don't know if it is nessecery to write a new Thread for all this streams, so if you know an easier solution to redirect the streams I'd like to hear about it.

Here my SSCCE:

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean run = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
        final Process pr = p.start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    pr.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("test");
                run = false;
            }
        });

        // read(is);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(System.in, pr.getOutputStream());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(pr.getInputStream(), System.out);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.out.println("finish");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(pr.getErrorStream(), System.err);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }).start();




    }

    public static void write(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = is.read(buf);

        if (len != -1) {
            byte[] data = new byte[len];

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                data[i] = buf[i];

            }

            os.write(data);
            os.flush();
        }

    }
}
```

What happens, is that I create a new Thread for every redirection of the streams, and the redirection itself happens via the `write(inputStream,outputStream)` method.

But the thread I use to check if the process is closed (`pr.waitFor()`) doesn't work as i thought it would. So I don't get noticed if the cmd is closed.

**EDIT2**

Ok I just forgot to start the Thread. But now I was able to get close to the problem.

The redirection of System.in to the process.getOutputStream() doesn't notice that the process is going to be closed. That's because `is.read(buf)` is a blocking method. So if I try to write a new command to the Process, then it notices that the streams should be closed and finishes the program.

If there is any solution for redirecting the Streams without threads, I'd like to implement it that way. I think this would be easier to use.

Comment: just forgot to start the thread...

Answer (score 2):

the main problem is you **didn't do `.start` on the thread** but i also want to suggest an improvement

wait for the process in the main thread:

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean run = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
        final Process pr = p.start();

        // read(is);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(System.in, pr.getOutputStream());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(pr.getInputStream(), System.out);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.out.println("finish");
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (run)
                    try {
                        write(pr.getErrorStream(), System.err);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }).start();


             try {
                 pr.waitFor();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             System.out.println("test");
             run = false;

    }

    public static void write(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = is.read(buf);

        if (len != -1) {
            byte[] data = new byte[len];

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                data[i] = buf[i];

            }

            os.write(data);
            os.flush();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Half way through my problem. I edited my question. Maybe you know a solution for the second problem?

Comment: Well, it helped to get notice that the process is closed. But the main problem is not solved. So sorry, but I will accept the solution that solves my main problem. I clicked on upvote, though.

Comment: @Loki understood. in that case try to edit the question, highlight the part the isn't working using "**" or "#" signs

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that is because your main thread could exit before all those threads complete. Try adding `pr.waitFor()` right at the end of your main function.

Comment: No, it's not closed at all. And when I try to write something via my redirection I get the Error: `java.io.IOException: The Pipe currently gets closed` So it seems it has problems closing the Pipe.